# Write a firefox plugin and access it from a java application

Tags: java, firefox, plugins

I want to write a firefox plugin which will communicate with a java application.
The plugin will have to notify the java application of the web page/ url being loaded.
The java application will take care of the rest.

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have authored a couple Firefox plugins with precisely this requirement.

One strategy is to use the JavaScript-to-Java bridge in Firefox, which permits the use of Java RMI. I found this approach slow and unstable, and the multithreading is painful.

My current solution is to open a `localhost` socket and use a textual protocol to communicate. See the [XULPlanet developer guide on sockets](http://xulplanet.com/tutorials/mozsdk/sockets.php) for how to open and read/write with sockets in Firefox JavaScript, and there's a [Sun tutorial on sockets in Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

The source code to one plugin I wrote (for Firefox and Eclipse) is available under the X11 aka MIT license: [Firedoclipse source](http://people.csail.mit.edu/maxg/uid/firedoclipse/src/). Under the `lib` directory is a component called `jsjr`, with several Java classes and a JavaScript XPCOM object that implement remote method invocation between Java and JavaScript. The `test` directory contains some unit tests. This remote method invocation would be overkill for sending only one kind of message in one direction, but you might find the code helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was hoping that is should be possible to use sockets rather than RMI. Thanks for verifying that.