# client side jar that controls parts of Firefox

Tags: java, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I am a Java programmer. I would like to write a client-side Java program that adds-on to Firefox to perform operations on the HTML received from a specific remote web site, BEFORE that HTML is displayed in the user's browser.  The client side Java program would have to:

1. Locate and read specific files on the local (end-user) machine on which it resides.
2. Check the URLs of web pages requested by Firefox.
3. If a URL requested through Firefox contains a specific domain:

   1. Iterate through the HTML text looking for `startcode` and `endcode`.
   2. Slice out the string between `startcode` and `endcode`.
   3. Transform the string between `startcode` and `endcode` using info from file on local pc.
   4. Replace the string between `startcode` and `endcode` with the transformed string.
   5. Allow the Firefox browser window to display the modified HTML.

Basically, the Java program would intercept incoming HTML from a specific web site and alter the contents before the contents are displayed on the user's screen.  How would I go about writing this kind of program?

Of course, I have administrative privileges on the computers that would run this program.  But I have never written a browser add on before.  I would like to write it in Java, but the code would need to always be on the client computer.  The code could never be on the server.  I do not know where to start this project.

Answer (score 2):

@Athafoud is correct in general. No browser supports Java out of the box.

Instead:

- You can write browser extensions for Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera in Javascript. E.g. the [firefox-addon](/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) has a link list to get you started with Firefox extension development.
- You can also write browser extensions for Firefox in C/C++ (to some extend) using either [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) or [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM).
- You can write some limited C++ stuff for Chrome via their [NaCL APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client).
- You could potentially write Java Applets for browsers that support the Java plugin and bundle them with and script them from your extension (to some extend) but that is a PITA.

Firefox extension APIs are the most capable as anything Firefox can do, extensions can do too (incl. calling into external libraries). Other browsers have far more limited extensibility/extension-facing APIs (due to architectural issues and sometimes in the name of security, although that bold security claim is... well, bold).

As for the particular requirements you gave in your question:

- Firefox extensions are capable of transforming raw HTTP responses (although this is a bit cumbersome), as well as the DOM once HTML is parsed (from javascript). Firefox can read/write all files in the file system (abiding OS-level ACLs, of course).
- Chrome extensions [are **not** capable of transforming raw HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18316107/484441) ATM, but you could modify the DOM once parsed. Also IIRC Chrome **cannot** read arbitrary files by default but you can manually enable read-access.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that you are able to use native java to write a firefox addon. You can use javascript. A good place to start is on [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) site.

There is also a good guide here [shortest-tutorial-for-firefox-extension](http://devilsworkshop.org/tips/shortest-tutorial-for-firefox-extensiontoolbar-development/347/), it is a bit old and the SDK has change, but i think is good start.

And a more update from mozzila itself [how-to-develop-firefox-extension](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/)

Comment: There must be some Firefox API that can be accessed using any language, including Java.

Comment: There was one (i cannot recall the name) but as i know it has been repealed. I do not know if this approach can help you [link(]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599291/write-a-firefox-plugin-and-access-it-from-a-java-application) or this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366195/using-java-python-libraries-in-programming-firefox-chrome-extensions)

Comment: OK.  If that is true, I am not committed to Firefox.  Are there other browsers for which I could write such a program in Java?

Comment: As far as i know, No there isn't. In chrome you can write using C or C++ if that helps

Comment: Thank you.  I bookmarked your links.  Let's wait and see who else responds to this.